# Wronskian different from 0..?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Having the differential equation $$y''+ay'+by=0~,$$if we know that the Wronskian determinant is different from $~0~$, how can we conclude that
$$-c_1~y_1(x_0)+c_2~y_2(x_0)=A$$  and
$$-c_1~y_1'(x_0)+c_2~y_2'(x_0)=B$$

where $~y_1,~y_2~$ solutions of the differential equation $$y''+ay'+by=0~,~~~~~~~~~~~~y(x_0)=A~~~~ \text{and}~~~~ y'(x_0)=B$$

Comment: http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/204/ConstantCoeff/linearIndependence.htm

Comment: Knowing that y=f(x) is any solution of the differential equation,how can I show,using the identities of the Wronskian,that there are constant terms c1,c2,so that:
c1*u1(0)+c2*u2(0)=f(0) and c1*u1'(0)+c2*u2'(0)=f'(0),if u1,u2 solutions of the differential equation y''+ay'+by=0?

Comment: I still don't know how to show that there are constant terms c1,c2,so that: c1*u1(0)+c2*u2(0)=f(0) and c1*u1'(0)+c2*u2'(0)=f'(0),if u1,u2 solutions of the differential equation y''+ay'+by=0.Do you have an idea how I could start?